# Order of convergence of a sequence for which $x_n=o(1)$ and $\log x_n=O(n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers satisfying

- $x_n\to 0$; and
- $n^{-1}(\log x_n)\to c<0$

as $n\to\infty$. I want to show that $x_n=O(\exp(n c))$; that is, the sequence $\{x_n\exp(-n c)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ remains bounded. I keep running in circles and I have been unable to come up with a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a counterexample: $x_n\equiv\exp(\sqrt{n}-n)$.